# Python Crash Course 2nd edition Chapter 8 - formatted_name.py

Tags: python

I'm learning Python from the book by Eric Matthes and I love the experience but even though I am  a beginner, I love to keep the code shorter.
I have a question regarding this piece of code:

`formatted_name.py`

```
def formatted_name(first_name, last_name):
    """Return a fully formatted name."""
    full_name=f"{first_name} {last_name}"
    return full_name.title()
musician=formatted_name('jimi','hendrix')
print(musician)
```

I love simplifying code, so I got the same result from:

```
def formatted_name(first_name, last_name):
    """Return a fully formatted name."""
    return (f"{first_name} {last_name}").title()
print(formatted_name('jimi','hendrix'))
```

However the book says 'When you call a function that returns a value, you need to provide a variable that the return value can be assigned to.'

Am I wrong here or can I do it like that?

Comment: You can do it like that, the book is eluding to the fact that if you need to use that return value more than once, it needs something to store the result to

Comment: Those are rules for readability and better understanding of code.

Comment: Often, you can do something any of a million different ways. The exact variable names can be damn near anything. The abstractions can vary. You'll want to develop a feel for why some ways are better than others. Personally, in this instance, I'd just return as you have done. It's still very simple to read. You've just had to come up with another variable name. I'd argue that your comment doesn't even do much to clarify what a formatted name is - the unclear part is "what are the features of a formatted name?", rather than "does the method named 'formatted_name' return a formatted name?".

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! Could you please show me an example of such a return call for reference?

Comment: the quote from the book is not related to the function itself but on the way you should use it in your code
in fact it's about this very line: musician=formatted_name('jimi','hendrix')

also in the end i feel the book code is "longer" but more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say your question is more about *style* than functionality and style isn't really a question of "right" or "wrong" of *personal preference*. So I'll provide my personal opinion.

#### Simplicity vs. brevity

> I love simplifying code

I would argue that "your code" isn't *simpler* than the "book's code", it's *shorter*. I'd say that "simple code" (the opposite would be "complex code") performs it's job in a way that is "easy to understand" using "a small number of steps" There are formal definitions of code complexity, e.g. [Cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity)

From that viewpoint, both code samples are equally simple/complex because they both use the same steps to perform the same job.

#### Benefits of using additional variables

There is a real benefit to storing data in variables like `full_name` and `formatted_name`: The ability to set breakpoints. You probably won't use a debugger on this simple code example. But when you're debugging complex code, breakpoints can really help you to figure out what's going wrong.

In Python 3.7 or newer, you can use the built-in [`breakpoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint) function:

```
def formatted_name(first_name, last_name):
    """Return a fully formatted name."""
    full_name=f"{first_name} {last_name}"

    breakpoint()  # Here, we can check the value of "full_name"

    return full_name.title()
musician=formatted_name('jimi','hendrix')
print(musician)
```